# Using IN in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

*Assuming this mySql table :

```
 id   | group |  members
 1    | blue  |     Bob
 2    | red   |     Tom 
 3    |green  |     Maria 
 4    |blue   |     Maria 
 5    |red    |     Bob 
 6    |red    |     Maria 
 7    |yellow |     Bob
```

How can I query this table in order to get the rows where members are both in group "blue" and "green

Using the "IN" in where clause does not work for me.

Expected result : "Maria"

## Edit :

Maybe I found something... If I use n variable in my "IN" array, so I should use the same n value in the "HAVING" part.
Tried with this statement and it seems to work. (comments appreciated)

```
    SELECT id,members
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE `team` IN('blue', 'red', 'green')
    GROUP BY members
    HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT team) >= 3
```

What is your opinion ?

Comment: show the query you tried

Comment: what query have you tried?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard, @juergen_d, @TZHX
Here is my sql statement :
    SELECT
    id,
    member
    FROM  my_table as f
    WHERE group IN('blue','green')
    GROUP BY  members
    HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT `group`) >= 2
Your statement is OK if there are only 2 variables in the "IN" clause.
But if I add a 3rd variable in it, I don't get what I expect. I mean, I expect to get 0 row.

Answer (score 1):

Group by the members and take only those having both, green and blue.

```
select members
from your_table
where `group` in ('blue','green')
group by members
having count(distinct `group`) = 2
```

The query will filter on records having only blue and green. Then it takes only membes that have 2 different groups - blue and green.

Comment: Then change `= 2` to `>= 2`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: Did you read the question? *How can I query this table in order to get the rows where members are both in group "blue" and "green"*

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: And the `having` part is essential an does not need to be changed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: Think about the `where` clause and test it if you like

Comment: couldn't you use `where group = 'green' and where group='blue' group by members`? Edit: Nevermind... that would show anyone with blue or green.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: I wrote that kind of query 1000 times. it will return the expected result. Be my guest. prove me wrong and build a http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @juergend sorry about that just realized I misunderstood your query... will remove the downvote as soon as SO let me. feel dumb ..

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: No problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from members mb
inner join members mg on mg.members = mb.members and mg.`group` = 'green'
where mb.`group` = 'blue'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05d8b2/8/0

It's a intersection (inner join) between two groups.

Answer (score 0):

select id from my_table A inner join my_table B
ON A.members = B.members 
where A.group ='blue' AND B.group ='green'

Comment: Your answer is duplicate of the answer given by andrei.mihail.nicolae 5 years ago. If you think you could make better answer then please extend your post with extra explanation.